# Criptografia SHA512 - XAMARIN

Tags: c#, mobile, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

Boa tarde, estou tentando criptografar uma string com SHA512, no projeto [PCL], Não estou conseguindo, alguém pode mostrar um exemplo de como fazer?

A ideia era fazer algo como:

```
public string Encripty(DateTime dataAtual, string stringQueQueroEncriptar){

return data = SHA512.secretKey("dataAtual").Hash("stringQueQueroEncriptar");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com [este post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/50703/how-to-use-sha-hash-in-xamarin), o namespace `System.Security.Cryptography` não é compatível com o PCL, mas o `Mono` sim.

Tente algo como:

```
protected override byte[] ComputeHash(byte[] data)
    {
        var input = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(data);

        var hasher = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithmNames.Sha512);
        var hashedBuf = hasher.HashData(input);

        byte[] result = new byte[hashedBuf.Length];
        CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(hashedBuf, out result);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Então, já tentei isso porém no PCL(Portable Class Labrary) não tem os assemblys relacionados a esta criptografia, e se eu tentar baixar pelo Nuguet, também não aceita.
Único pacote que consegui instalar pelo Nuguet foi o PCLCrypto, mas nele não consegui criar uma criptografia no modelo que informei, inserindo uma chave secreta, os exemplos que encontrei só informão o conteúdo a ser criptografado.

Comment: Editei o post. Dê uma olhada e veja se funciona agora.

Comment: Foi não cara, copiei e colei, tentei inportar o assembly Mono.Android, sem sucesso. não reconhece esse código. Obrigado pelo esforço, continuo tentando aqui...

Answer (score 1):

ACHEI \o/ - Instalando do Nuguet o PCLCrypto(ao instalar, o assembly Validation tem que estar aparecendo tbm na lista de referencias, senão instala manualmente entrando na pasta do PCLCrypto). só mandar esse código aí e sucesso!

```
public string CreateHash(string date, string userId) {



            IMacAlgorithmProvider mac = WinRTCrypto.MacAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(MacAlgorithm.HmacSha512);

            byte[] keyMaterial = WinRTCrypto.CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(date, crypto.Encode());

            ICryptographicKey cryptoKey = mac.CreateKey(keyMaterial);

            byte[] hash = WinRTCrypto.CryptographicEngine.Sign(cryptoKey, WinRTCrypto.CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(userId, Encoding.UTF8));

            StringBuilder hashHMAC = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++) {
                hashHMAC.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));
            }

            return hashHMAC.ToString();
        }
```